# How to perform a looping task in Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, video, ffmpeg

I have files like these:

```
01 - A.wav
02 - B.wav
03 - C.wav
an so on until
15 - BLA.wav
```

I want to convert with ffmpeg those .wav files to .mp4 with background I've been already made. And the command lines I have are:

```
dirinwav="/home/akrogun/Videos/wav" && \                  # input dir where wav files stored
diringraphics="/home/akrogun/Videos/graphics/" && \       # input dir where background image stored
dirout="/home/akrogun/Videos/ffmpegout/" && \             # final output dir
file01="01 - A" && \
file02="02 - B" && \
file03="03 - C" && \
...
file15="15 - BLA" && \
\
echo "Encoding " $file01..... && \
file_n=$file01 && \
number=01 && \
ffmpeg -y -i "$dirinwav/$file_n.WAV" -acodec libfdk_aac -b 128k out-aac.aac && \
ffmpeg -y -i "$diringraphics/background.jpg" -i "$diringraphics/$number.png" -filter_complex "overlay" out-background.png && \
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i out-background.png -i out-aac.aac -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 800k -acodec copy -shortest "$dirout/$file_n.mp4" && \
printf "\n" && \
\
echo "Encoding " $file02..... && \
file_n=$file02 && \
number=02 && \
ffmpeg -y -i "$dirinwav/$file_n.WAV" -acodec libfdk_aac -b 128k out-aac.aac && \
ffmpeg -y -i "$diringraphics/background.jpg" -i "$diringraphics/$number.png" -filter_complex "overlay" out-background.png && \
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i out-background.png -i out-aac.aac -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 800k -acodec copy -shortest "$dirout/$file_n.mp4" && \
printf "\n" && \
...
echo "Encoding " $file15..... && \
file_n=$file15 && \
number=15 && \
ffmpeg -y -i "$dirinwav/$file_n.WAV" -acodec libfdk_aac -b 128k out-aac.aac && \
ffmpeg -y -i "$diringraphics/background.jpg" -i "$diringraphics/$number.png" -filter_complex "overlay" out-background.png && \
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i out-background.png -i out-aac.aac -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 800k -acodec copy -shortest "$dirout/$file_n.mp4" && \
printf "\n"
```

Those command line are just working fine, but, as you can see, I have to repeat those ffmpeg stuff for 15 times. How do I change those command line with for loop function in terminal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found this link and I hope this is help you. [https://www.baeldung.com/linux/repeat-command](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/repeat-command)

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
Thank you SannUlya and  Artur Meinild